# semaphore equivalent for processes?

Tags: c, linux, process, synchronization

I have a parent process that forks two children. I need to force a certain order for when these child processes run.

For example, the parent process takes a "command" from a file, and depending on that command, the parent will either pass that command to child a or child b using unnamed pipes. I need stuff to happen in the children in the same order that the parent received the command from the file.

The way I was using semaphores did not work between processes. Any ideas?

Comment: A bit of the question is missing, right around "same order".

Comment: If you're asking how to block on a child until it's done, just use a second unnamed pipe (the parent can block on a read until the child writes to it -- doesn't matter what is written).

Comment: Looked into [Logical Clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_clock) ?

Comment: @Ignacio: Not sure what you're getting at. I can see the whole question.

Comment: Semaphores can be used to synchronize between processes. Your statement is not correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semaphores work just fine between processes.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  // Error checking omitted for expository purposes
  sem_t *sem = sem_open("test_semaphore", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0, 1);
  sem_unlink("test_semaphore");
  int child = fork();
  printf("pid %d about to wait\n", getpid());
  sem_wait(sem);
  printf("pid %d done waiting\n", getpid());
  sleep(1);
  printf("pid %d done sleeping\n", getpid());
  sem_post(sem);

  if(child > 0)
  {
    int status;
    printf("parent done, waiting for child\n");
    wait(&status);
  }

  printf("pid %d exiting\n", getpid());
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ time ./a.out
pid 61414 about to wait
pid 61414 done waiting
pid 61415 about to wait
pid 61414 done sleeping
parent done, waiting for child
pid 61415 done waiting
pid 61415 done sleeping
pid 61415 exiting
pid 61414 exiting

real    0m2.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s
```

Comment: +1.  But I think you can make this slightly cleaner by calling `sem_unlink` immediately following `sem_open`.  The semaphore will continue to exist until all references to it are closed, e.g. by the processes exiting.  The advantage of unlinking immediately is that if the parent crashes you are not left with a stray semaphore that never goes away.

Comment: what does the 0644 argument mean in the sem_open call?

Comment: @Nemo: Good point, updated.  @ladookie: It sets the permissions (like [`chmod(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod) on the semaphore, in case other processes decide that they want to open the same semaphore with `sem_open`.  See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open).

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: the fork() got chopped out when you edited.

Comment: Wouldn't each process has its own address space?. Would this not let process 1 and process 2 to have their own individual private semaphore variables?. Please clarify as I am searching for resolving similar problem.

Comment: @Pavan: No, semaphores are kernel objects, and each process has its own independent handle to the same underlying kernel object.  This works identically to how file descriptors referring to the same file object (including open mode, offset, etc.) can be shared between parent and child processes after a `fork()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IPC semaphores they also work for forks. Look here: http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder Chapter 5 will give you the informations you need.