# If I initialize a mutex before creating child processes, will all the children honor the mutex?

Tags: linux, process, mutex

I've done a bit of digging, and the closest I've come to direct answer to my question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659866/32836).

I've created a mutex then spin into a loop where I listen for activity on a TCP/IP port, fork, respond, then exit from the child.  Part of the 'respond' requires that the child process access hardware autonomously, that is protected by a mutex.

If I initialize a mutex before creating child processes, will all the potentially concurrently running children honor the mutex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by default.

You have to store the mutex in a shared memory block. You can get one with SysV IPC or with the `MAP_SHARED` flag to `mmap()`.

You also have to set the attributes on the mutex properly. You need to make a mutex attribute with `pthread_mutexattr_init()` and call `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()`, then pass that attribute to `pthread_mutex_init()`.

If you do not use shared memory, the child processes will not be able to see the mutex state because each will be using a private copy. If you do not set the pshared attribute the mutex will probably crash the program because it will not expect other processes to be changing the data.